# IntelliJ: Setting different working directories per class in multiple class tests

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, configuration

I want to run a suite of tests in IntelliJ within a single run configuration,
and I want each class of Junit tests to have it's own work directory.
What I tried to do was to set the Working directory to `$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$\$FileClass$\`
However, I'm getting the error "Cannot start process, the working directory 'c:/...' does not exist".

I would even settle on having the same workdir per class and long as there's a way to make sure it's cleaned after each class.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Would JUnit 5 temporary directories be a solution? See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-built-in-extensions-TempDirectory

Comment: I'm using JUnit 4 :(

Comment: JUnit 4 has this feature too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40130300

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample of project showing what kind of tests suites do you plan to run? Thanks